# Correct usage of lbs. as in "pounds" of weight

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations

What is the correct way to say:
"All items over 5 lbs. are excluded."
I'm specifically asking about "lbs." or is it "lb."?  American English if it matters.

Also is "5lbs." ever correct?  Or is it "5 lbs."?

Comment: Assuming it's not casual usage, I'd recommend "All items over five pounds are excluded," instead.  Most style guided recommend spelling out numbers of ten or less, and in such a case I'd spell out the unit, too.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades "5 lbs." (or similar) is far superior when it comes to signage, though.

Comment: I am amazed that there can be such spirited debate over whether a period can follow an abbreviation and no-one notes that pounds is NOT a unit of weight! Did the OP mean to refer to mass?

Comment: @Fortiter In case the copy text I provided was not enough of a clue, I was just double-checking this for some copy that will go in an e-commerce shopping app.  It's not my job at all to check this, but what someone had wrote for the "5 lb" part looked totally wrong, so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Pounds does not only refer to mass.  It also refers to the weight that one pound of mass weighs on the earth.  See the Wikipedia entry on Pound (Force).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In scientific publications, units of measurement are almost never pluralized when abbreviated. This should remain true for general use, as well.  You should therefore never write "lbs."  You should technically not need a period after "lb" either, unless it's at the end of a sentence.

The abbreviation "lb" comes from the Latin *libra*, which is itself short for *libra pondo*, or "pound weight."  And in any case, the plural of *libra* would be *librae*, not *libras*.

And, again in scientific papers, there is always a space between the quantity and the unit.

Comment: Agreed that _5 lb_ is correct for scientific usage, but _5 lbs._ is common in general English, and some style guides require the period. Please don't recommend “never” for general use without evidence from a _general_ English style guide.

Comment: @BraddSzonye & **esp., the up voters** : Like to know of *any* style guide that recommends "All items over 5 lbs. are excluded."  with a pluralized *lbs*. Never make a universalized comment. And do not up vote just to show your ignorance.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I don't think Imperial (or 'English' if you're in the US) units find much currency in any kind of scientific literature.   The use of metric is near universal.  Might prove difficult to find any kind of contemporary example!

Comment: @Marko The questioner asks about “American English,” _not_ scientific literature, which is why I have reservations about this answer. Metric usage is far from universal here.

Comment: @Kris I don't think anyone suggested that style guides recommend pluralized _lbs_ (although it's common in actual usage). I was noting that some guides require the _period_ when abbreviating English units (_lb._ versus _lb_).

Answer (score 15):

Grammar Girl has a related article, [“Units of Measure.”](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/units-of-measure.aspx) The key points:

- **Put a space between numbers and units of measure.** Typographers prefer a thin space, but you shouldn't generally need to worry about it.
- **Abbreviations are generally the same for singular and plural units:** While *lbs* isn't incorrect, *lb* is better for formal and scientific use. Never pluralize metric system units like meters and grams.
- **Period usage varies with style guide.** They're more common in American writing. However, never use periods with metric system units.

Comment: Worth adding that metric units are never pluralised. Half a pound is 227g, not 227gs.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Plural abbreviations are rare even in English units: _lbs_ is one of the few exceptions. Thanks for the suggestion, I updated the answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, only if we are talking about avoirdupois. If troy is intended, then half a pound is 186.5 g. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing 2.3 kg instead of any of 5 lbs., 5lbs., 5 lb. or 5lb.  Historically, however, the forms  “5 lb” and “5 lbs” appear to have been used more than either of the others (according to [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=5+lbs%2C5lbs%2C5lb%2C5+lb%2C5+lb+.&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C5%20lbs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5lbs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5lb%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lb%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lb%20.%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C5%20lbs%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C5lbs%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C5lb%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lb%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lb%20.%3B%2Cc1) for *5 lbs,5lbs,5lb,5 lb,5 lb .* [where *5 lb .* represents *5 lb.* ie has a period after *lb* as part of the search]) :
[image: ngrams of 5 terms]

Note, if you click on the [book links](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=5+lbs%2C5lbs%2C5lb&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) on the ngrams page, you will note that in many instances the 5 is after a decimal point, eg, “12.5 lbs.”.

Note, naturally *5 lb* occurs more often than other forms because *5 lb* occurs in every instance of any of {*5 lbs, 5 lb, 5 lb., 5 lbs.*}.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=5+lbs%2C5+lb%2C5+lb+.%2C5+lbs+.&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C5%20lbs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lb%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lb%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lbs%20.%3B%2Cc0) for *5 lbs,5 lb,5 lb .,5 lbs .* shows that *5 lb.* and *5 lbs.* nowadays occur with nearly equal frequency, the latter slightly more frequently.  Before 1980, *5 lb.* occurred rather more frequently than *5 lbs.*

Comment: _2.3 kg_ is not appropriate for general use in American English, and _2.3 Kg_ (with capital _K_) is incorrect everywhere. Helpful Ngram though, thanks!

Comment: @BraddSzonye, fixed kg

Comment: Note that this Ngram does not validate that "items over 5lb are excluded" is valid.  "5lb" (or, better, "5 lb" or "5-lb") is valid as an adjective.  So most of these instances are something like "get a 5lb bag of flour."

Comment: This could be grossly misleading. nGrams need to be handled with extreme discretion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers – I updated figure.  Yes, 5 lb occurs structurally in all of {5 lbs, 5 lb, 5 lb., 5 lbs.} so is most common, but as noted in ngrams in last paragraph of answer *5 lb.* now occurs less often than *5 lbs.*

Comment: Is this correct, then, if I chose to abbreviate? *My uncle weighs 350 lb. (Not: 350 lbs.)*

Comment: @whippoorwill, either form is ok; use whichever you like.  The *lbs* form's frequency of use is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

"lbs" is never correct, lb is an abbreviation for Libra (Latin for Balance/Scales), and is both singular and plural it should always be lb.

Comment: Perhaps you should read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)) which says: _"The **commonly used abbreviation lbs** to indicate the plural unit of measurement does not reflect Latin usage, in which lb is both the singular and plural abbreviation."_

Comment: @Manish wiki doesn't mention that any more.